# How to use a converter on AutoQuery

Tags: servicestack

I have an autoquery implementation like so:

```
public QueryResponse<BlogDto> Get(BlogsLookUpRequest request)
{
    AutoMapping.RegisterConverter((Blog from) => {
        var to = from.ConvertTo<BlogDto>(skipConverters: true); // avoid infinite recursion
        to.Category = string.Join(",", from.BlogToBlogCategories.Select(x => x.BlogCategoryId.ToString()).Distinct());
        return to;
    });


    var q = _AutoQuery.CreateQuery(request, base.Request);
    var results = _AutoQuery.Execute(request, q);
    return results;
}
```

My autoquery type is `QueryDb<Blog, BlogDto>`.

The converter doesn't get called.  I want to flatten my junction table object into a csv.  Is it possible to define some custom mapping behavior for this in autoquery mapping?

If not, what is the best way to alter the result?

Edit:

I got it working by declaring another type `public class BlogEntityQuery : QueryDb<Blog>` that doesn't have a route.  Then did this:

```
public QueryResponse<BlogDto> Get(BlogsLookUpRequest request)
{
    AutoMapping.RegisterConverter((Blog from) => {
        var to = from.ConvertTo<BlogDto>(skipConverters: true); // avoid infinite recursion
        to.Category = string.Join(",", from.BlogToBlogCategories.Select(x => x.BlogCategoryId.ToString()).Distinct());
        return to;
    });

    var q = _AutoQuery.CreateQuery(request, base.Request);
    var rawResults = _AutoQuery.Execute(new BlogEntityQuery().PopulateWith(request), q);
    var results = new QueryResponse<BlogDto>().PopulateWith(rawResults);
    return results;
}
```

It works but feels a bit hacky. As AutoQuery is performing automatic mapping I feel like there should be an option to register a converter for it to use.

Answer (score 0):

[AutoMapping Registrations](https://docs.servicestack.net/auto-mapping#advanced-mapping-using-converters) like all configuration should **only be configured once on Startup**, e.g. in `AppHost.Configure()`.

AutoQuery itself **doesn't do any mapping**, the AutoQuery Response result set is populated directly from the DB results which is why no converters are used.